# Expo-status-bar doesn't update after reload

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using `expo-status-bar` in my managed project, when I first reload the `expo-go` client app the status bar background color won't mount, it only updates after navigating to a new screen.

```react-native
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
      <StatusBar
        style="light"
        backgroundColor={"#1c1917"}
      />
      <SignUp />
    </SafeAreaView>
```

The status bar background color is set to white after reloading and only updates to `#1c1917` after some navigations.

The same occurs in the build version for Android.